# Javascript console logging 2 times the function using geolocation api from the browser

Tags: javascript, html

SCRIPT

```
"<script>

function success(pos) {

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${pos.coords.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${pos.coords.longitude}`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

</script>"
```

Hey all, I have this script in the HTML file, and when I run the html, the console log 2 times the latitude, and longitude. What can the problem be?

I tried to remove everything down just to sucess function and the last line "navigator...", but it still happens.
I only want the script to display 1 time latitude and longitude.

Comment: Are you sure the script is not included twice somehow? How are you adding the script to the page?

Comment: what happens if you do not include a ref to error function in getCurrentPosition()?

Comment: @epascarello No the script is not included twice.

Comment: @ThisGuy unsure what difference that would make.

Comment: @ch1c8 Really impossible for us to guess. That code should not be running twice. Something is different. We need more details.

Comment: @ThisGuy It gives the same output, 2 times the latitude and longitude again

Comment: Make a new page with just that script and barebone html. Does it happen?

Comment: @epascarello No it doesn't happen, now I know that the problem is from the project

Comment: @epascarello One thing that I noticed is that when I see in the console the origin of the 4 lines, 2 say that it is from (index):1227, and the other 2 say it is from VM2286:7 but when I click them and see where there are from, it's from the exact file (index.html)

Comment: check your rendered index.html file for line 1227. the VM2286:7 should be your console. maybe try to rename your function and see if it is called twice again.

Comment: @thisGuy still called twice...

Comment: Inspect your html in the browser. Look at the code...